# Debug.Write() works in MyClass but not in Form1 class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

inside Form1.cs I added some Debug statements to trace user actions.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("user clicked: 'button1'");
        myClass.MyFunction();
    }
```

Similar statements work fine in other classes in this project, but not here.
At one point earlier, this worked for Form1 but I can't isolate what changed.
I know the button works because myClass.MyFunction gets called (and its Debug statements work) Any reason why this should be?

(my project settings/ build / checkbox "Define DEBUG constant" is checked)

[edit] I switched to using Console.WriteLine(), which seems to output to the Output Window when debugging. I dis not know that.

Comment: Is it a debug build?  The constant is just that, a constant.  Doesn't mean you're in a debug build where the output can be produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("user Clicked:'button1');
```

Try

```
Console.WriteLine("user clicked: 'button1'");
```

Comment: I started with Console.Write but this is a windows Forms app, so I have to set it to console app to get that working and remember to set it back before release. Routing information to the Output window feels  cleaner.

Comment: Ok...it looks like Console.Write will in fact output to the output window when debugging a Windows Forms program. selecting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want and where u have stuck. but anyhow
use a break point to debug your code ... and 
use

```
MessageBox.Show("user Clicked:'button1');
```

instead of this

```
system.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("user Clicked:'button1');
```

Would you tell me more what you are trying to do....?

Comment: I just wish to keep track of user input and program output: what buttons clicked, what folders are chosen, what lists are compiled using those inputs, etc...

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, create a new Label named debug and set its text to your message:

```
if (buttonClicked)
{
    debug.text = "A button was clicked";
}
```